# Static language to render images in loop - Upload through Django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I uploaded images with admin, but cannot render them in the template. What am I missing?

Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_DIRS = { os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
}

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Models.py

```
class Function(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fimage = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "name{},id{}".format(self.name, self.id)
```

HTML

```
{% for function in functions %}
<a href="function_page/{{function.id}}">
<img id=function_menu_pic src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{function.fimage.url}}"></a>
{% endfor %}
```

Views.py

```
def main(request):
   context = {
   "functions": Function.objects.all()
    }
return render (request, 'project/main.html', context)
```

Urls.py

```
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

When I upload the files they are going to a media file that is at the same level as manage.py. I'm not sure how the routing works from there.

I'm getting this message for all the images:

```
Not Found: /media/images/lpo.png
[02/Feb/2018 09:54:01] "GET /media/images/1_ssOAG27.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2748
```

[image: html template]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `{{MEDIA_URL}}` in img src and put quotes`"` in id..

```
<img id="function_menu_pic" src="{{function.fimage.url}}">
```

Comment: No change. Do I need anything in the views?

Comment: @dev_2018 you don't need to change anything in views. Just try giving absolute path in `MEDIA_ROOT` once.

Comment: Thank you! I followed your advice. I didn't know how to set the absolute path but I found this blog. https://timmyomahony.com/blog/static-vs-media-and-root-vs-path-in-django/ It's working perfectly. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a long time to fix this, so I want to share how I fixed it:

I followed Astik's advice above and made changes to the template.

I reset my absolute path. This blog helped immensely.
 [Timothey Mahony blog](https://timmyomahony.com/blog/static-vs-media-and-root-vs-path-in-django/)

```
`ENV_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(ENV_PATH, 'media/')`
```

I hope this helps if you ever get stuck in the same place I was!

https://timmyomahony.com/blog/static-vs-media-and-root-vs-path-in-django/